# R-value in C++0x

Tags: c++11

Rvalues IMHO are great improvement in C++, but at the beginning they're  quite confusing. Please look at code below:

```
#include <string>

std::string && foo ()
{
    std::string message ("Hello!");
    
    return std::move (message);
}

void bar (const std::string &message2)
{
    if (message2 == "Bye Bye!")
        return;
}

int main ()
{
    bar (foo ());
}
```

Reference `message2` is last owner of original `message` object returned by `foo()`, right?

Comment: this question is mixing the concepts of values and objects slightly.  The last object with the value "`Hello!"` is an unnamed temporary in `main`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it's not right. You fell for the usual trap one make when discovering rvalue reference, as did Motti in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3035448/5825294)! (And I did this mistake too, in my earlier test with rvalue reference.)

If you don't want to shoot yourself in the foot when dealing with rvalue reference, internalize this:

**In most case, a function returning an rvalue reference is as foolish as a function returning a normal reference.**

Because rvalue references are... references! So if you return a reference - rvalue or not - to `message`, you return a reference to an object that was just destroyed, because it went out of scope, so you return a dangling reference. It's a bug.

Also, don't write `return std::move(message)` because the compiler knows already that `message` need not be copied nor moved, but constructed directly in the memory location at the call site, so there is no need to recast it with `std::move`. And actually, writing `return std::move(something)` can *prevent* optimization.

So, the correct and most efficient way is:

```
#include <string>
std::string foo (void)
{
    std::string message ("Hello!");
    return message;
}

void bar (const std::string& message2)
{
    if (message2 == "Bye Bye!")
        return;
}

int main ()
{
    bar (foo());
}
```

Good old C++03 :)
Because NRVO kicks in and there is no copy, no move, only one construction.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**  Returning an r-value reference isn't something you want to do. This answer was originally written when I was still getting to grasps with C++11s r-value references.

---

You're right, `message2` will be constructed using the move constructor so it may cannibalize the memory allocated by `message` in `foo`, however this may not be what happens if the [small string optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/707014/why-vc-strings-are-not-reference-counted/711138#711138) is used then the move constructor for a short string will not be any more efficient than the copy constructor.

Another thing to note is that you don't have to explicitly use `std::move` when returning a value, return values are known to be r-value  references.