# What does the double ampersand return type mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, ampersand

I've stumbled upon such syntax as this:

```
int&& move(int&& x)
{
    return x;
}
```

which is supposedly how the `std::move` function is implemented, but I don't quite understand what does the return type (&&) actually means.

I did googled it and failed to fail an answer, could someone please explain this to me?

EDIT:

Most of my confusion comes from the fact the return of a function is already an rvalue so I don't understand what && can change there.. not sure if I make sense or not.

Comment: The double-ampersand is what is commonly known as [rvalue references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors).

Comment: An r-value reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5481539/what-does-t-double-ampersand-mean-in-c11?rq=1

Comment: `&&` is just shorthand for `and`. You could equally and more readably write the code as `int and move (int and x)`.

Comment: @KerrekSB I see what you did there. ;)

Comment: like i said, I did read most of this stuff, and I understood what accepting a && value is, but my question is about && return type, which nobody seems to mention or explain.

Comment: @Vladp It means exactly the same as what it means in function parameters. `int&& x` means the parameter `x` is an rvalue reference to `int`, and `int&& move(...)` means the function `move` returns an rvalue reference to `int`. I can understand that that doesn't tell you much, but it's really not clear from your question what more you want to know. Can you clarify?

Comment: This is *NOT* a duplicate; there are articles out there about i it is a good or bad thing to return a r-value reference. By closing this question sending to another one that doesn't mention return types you are neglecting the possibility ti have an answer.

Comment: @Emilio I don't understand why you think this is not a duplicate. He isn't asking if it's a good or a bad thing; he's asking *what it is*. The duplicate answers that adequately.

Comment: @CodyGray: It ask what it is **in return type**. Something the redirected question don't mention.

Comment: I'm so confused about this now, so I'll accept the answer and forget about it.

Comment: Sure it does. It talks about rvalue references, which is exactly what this question is about. I don't understand what all the confusion is about. If you want a question that discusses whether this is useful or not, see here: [Is there any case where a return of a RValue Reference (&&) is useful?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770253/is-there-any-case-where-a-return-of-a-rvalue-reference-is-useful)

Comment: @CodyGray: That should be the proper **answer**, not the one suggested in the closing of this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From: http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#rval

The `&&` indicates an "rvalue reference". An rvalue reference can bind to an rvalue (but not to an lvalue):

```
X a;
X f();
X& r1 = a;      // bind r1 to a (an lvalue)
X& r2 = f();    // error: f() is an rvalue; can't bind

X&& rr1 = f();  // fine: bind rr1 to temporary
X&& rr2 = a;    // error: bind a is an lvalue
```

Comment: The question is, what is the difference between `X f()` and `X&& f()`.  This doesn't answer that question whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

In that case, the move function is using the so-called `rvalue references` - relatively new C++ feature. It is nicely explained in [this article](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html).