# std::vector to string with custom delimiter

Tags: c++, string, vector

I would like to copy the contents of a `vector` to one long `string` with a custom delimiter. So far, I've tried:

```
// .h
string getLabeledPointsString(const string delimiter=",");
// .cpp
string Gesture::getLabeledPointsString(const string delimiter) {
    vector<int> x = getLabeledPoints();
    stringstream  s;
    copy(x.begin(),x.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(s,delimiter));
    return s.str();
}
```

but I get

```
no matching function for call to ‘std::ostream_iterator<int, char, std::char_traits<char> >::ostream_iterator(std::stringstream&, const std::string&)’
```

I've tried with `charT*` but I get

```
error iso c++ forbids declaration of charT with no type
```

Then I tried using `char` and `ostream_iterator<int>(s,&delimiter)`
but I get strange characters in the string.

Can anyone help me make sense of what the compiler is expecting here?

Comment: yes wouldn't it be nice if the compiler kindly told you what type it was expecting. Incidentally you will get a comma after your last element too.

Comment: The most elegant way is to use boost::algorithm::join() for this as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/6334153/2056686

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[Use `delimiter.c_str()` as the delimiter](http://ideone.com/dnVp6):

```
copy(x.begin(),x.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(s,delimiter.c_str()));
```

That way, you get a `const char*` pointing to the string, which is what `ostream_operator` expects from your `std::string`.

Comment: +1, but also note that this will write a trailing `delimiter` in the output.

Comment: I'm not sure about the performance here. A `stringstream` manages its own buffer, so it must grow dynamically. Here you know before generating the string what length it's going to be, so you should reserve the buffer before concatenating.

Comment: "you know before generating the string what length it's going to be" - or at any rate you know an upper bound. If stringstream grows its buffer exponentially then I wouldn't worry about performance, but I don't know whether that's the case.

Answer (score 24):

C++11:

```
vector<string> x = {"1", "2", "3"};
string s = std::accumulate(std::begin(x), std::end(x), string(),
                                [](string &ss, string &s)
                                {
                                    return ss.empty() ? s : ss + "," + s;
                                });
```

Comment: Looks neat, but wouldn't this create many strings in the process? Any way to improve this using string stream?

Comment: no, sttringsream is slower even more.

in fact if you have only container of strings it is better to write usual for-loop like
`code`

string result;
result.reserve(128);

for (auto &it: x)
{
    if (!result.emty())
    {
         result.append(",");
    }
    result.append(it);
}
`code`

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but that's not what the code above does. It's not appending - it's generating new strings.

Comment: You can avoid the conditional if you start from `begin(x)+1`, with `*begin(x)` as initial element.

Comment: @xtofl that will fail for an empty vector where `begin == end`

Comment: any reason you are passing non-const references?

Comment: Great solution to join operation. But producing initial delimiter. If you don't want to delimit empty strings use rather `return B.empty() ? A : (A.empty() ? B : A + " " + B);` And the signature of lambda could be `[](const std::string& A, const std::string& B)`.

Comment: great answer - especially if you make it a constexpr function; then all the performance issues everyone raises go away

Comment: See this post, clean and beautiful

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39467552/1334202

Answer (score 13):

Another way to do it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
string join(const T& v, const string& delim) {
    ostringstream s;
    for (const auto& i : v) {
        if (&i != &v[0]) {
            s << delim;
        }
        s << i;
    }
    return s.str();
}

int main() {
    cout << join(vector<int>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}), ",") << endl;
}
```

(c++11 range-based for loop and 'auto' though)

Answer (score 13):

This is an extension to the two answers already provided above as run-time performance seemed to be a theme in the comments. I would have added it as comments, but I do not have that privilege yet.

I tested 2 implementations for run-time performance using Visual Studio 2015:

Using stringstream:

```
std::stringstream result;
auto it = vec.begin();
result << (unsigned short)*it++;
for (; it != vec.end(); it++) {
    result << delimiter;
    result << (unsigned short)*it;
}
return result.str();
```

Using accumulate:

```
std::string result = std::accumulate(std::next(vec.begin()), vec.end(),
    std::to_string(vec[0]),
    [&delimiter](std::string& a, uint8_t b) {
    return a + delimiter+ std::to_string(b);
});
return result;
```

Release build run-time performance was close with a couple subtleties.

The accumulate implementation was slightly faster (20-50ms, ~10-30% of the overall run-time (~180ms) on 1000 iterations over a 256 element vector). However, the `accumulate` implementation was only faster when the `a` parameter to the lambda function was passed by reference. Passing the `a` parameter by value resulted in a similar run-time difference favoring the `stringstream` implementation. The `accumulate` implementation also improved some when the result string was returned directly rather than assigned to a local variable that was immediately returned. YMMV with other C++ compilers.

The Debug build was 5-10 times slower using `accumulate` so I think the extra string creation noted in several comments above is resolved by the optimizer.

I was looking at a specific implementation using a `vector` of `uint8_t` values. The full test code follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <numeric>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
typedef vector<uint8_t> uint8_vec_t;

string concat_stream(const uint8_vec_t& vec, string& delim = string(" "));
string concat_accumulate(const uint8_vec_t& vec, string& delim = string(" "));

string concat_stream(const uint8_vec_t& vec, string& delimiter)
{
    stringstream result;

    auto it = vec.begin();
    result << (unsigned short)*it++;
    for (; it != vec.end(); it++) {
        result << delimiter;
        result << (unsigned short)*it;
    }
    return result.str();
}

string concat_accumulate(const uint8_vec_t& vec, string& delimiter)
{
    return accumulate(next(vec.begin()), vec.end(),
        to_string(vec[0]),
        [&delimiter](string& a, uint8_t b) {
        return a + delimiter + to_string(b);
    });
}

int main()
{
    const int elements(256);
    const int iterations(1000);

    uint8_vec_t test(elements);
    iota(test.begin(), test.end(), 0);

    int i;
    auto stream_start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    string join_with_stream;
    for (i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
        join_with_stream = concat_stream(test);
    }
    auto stream_end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    auto acc_start = chrono::steady_clock::now();
    string join_with_acc;
    for (i = 0; i < iterations; ++i) {
        join_with_acc = concat_accumulate(test);
    }
    auto acc_end = chrono::steady_clock::now();

    cout << "Stream Results:" << endl;
    cout << "    elements: " << elements << endl;
    cout << "    iterations: " << iterations << endl;
    cout << "    runtime: " << chrono::duration<double, milli>(stream_end - stream_start).count() << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "    result: " << join_with_stream << endl;

    cout << "Accumulate Results:" << endl;
    cout << "    elements: " << elements << endl;
    cout << "    iterations: " << iterations << endl;
    cout << "    runtime: " << chrono::duration<double, milli>(acc_end - acc_start).count() << " ms" << endl;
    cout << "    result:" << join_with_acc << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I love that you provided performance numbers -- very useful for making a decision one way or the other, thanks!

Comment: Just to state the obvious:  `concat_stream()` and `concat_accumulate()` only work for non empty vectors.

Answer (score 9):

```
std::string Gesture::getLabeledPointsString(const std::string delimiter) {
  return boost::join(getLabeledPoints(), delimiter);
}
```

I am not that convinced about introducting `getLabeledPointsString` at this point ;)

Comment: ehehehheheh is there a cpp without boost? +1 for boost, thanks!

Comment: @nkint: Oh you can certainly program without boost. But that's about as difficult as Python without its libraries: you just need to create all the tools by yourself ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
string join(const vector<string> & v, const string & delimiter = ",") {
    string out;
    if (auto i = v.begin(), e = v.end(); i != e) {
        out += *i++;
        for (; i != e; ++i) out.append(delimiter).append(*i);
    }
    return out;
}
```

A few points:

- you don't need an extra conditional to avoid an extra trailing delimiter
- make sure you don't crash when the vector is empty
- don't make a bunch of temporaries (e.g. don't do this: x = x + d + y)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I have a similar problem and none of the above answers suits all my needs, so I'll post here my solution.

My requirements are:

- I need a generic solution able to work with any iterable container and with any data type, of course for custom data types you'll have to provide a suitable `operator<<()`
- I need an easy way to apply transforms to the data (for example, by default `int8_t` and `uint8_t` are handled as `char`s by `std::stringstream`: maybe this is what you want or maybe not, so I want to be able to make this choice)
- I want to be able to specify the delimiter as a string literal, but also accept `char`s and `std::string`s
- I like to have the ability to add enclosing characters, but this is probably very personal taste

This assumes C++11.
I choose to use `std::stringstream` because it implements a standard but still customizable way to convert something to a string.
Any comments are very welcome.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream> // used only in main
#include <vector> // used only in main

template< typename T >
typename std::iterator_traits< T >::value_type
identity(typename std::iterator_traits< T >::value_type v) {
  return v;
}

template< typename T > using IdentityType = decltype(identity< T >);

template< class InItr,
          typename StrType1 = const char *,
          typename StrType2 = const char *,
          typename StrType3 = const char *,
          typename Transform = IdentityType< InItr > >
std::string join(InItr first,
                 InItr last,
                 StrType1 &&sep = ",",
                 StrType2 &&open = "[",
                 StrType3 &&close = "]",
                 Transform tr = identity< InItr >) {

  std::stringstream ss;

  ss << std::forward< StrType2 >(open);

  if (first != last) {

    ss << tr(*first);

    ++first;
  }

  for (; first != last; ++first)
    ss << std::forward< StrType1 >(sep) << tr(*first);

  ss << std::forward< StrType3 >(close);

  return ss.str();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  const std::vector< int > vec{2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

  std::cout << join(vec.begin(), vec.end()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << join(vec.begin(), vec.end(), "|", "(", ")",
                    [](int v){ return v + v; }) << std::endl;

  const std::vector< char > vec2{2, 4, 6, 8, 10};
  std::cout << join(vec2.begin(), vec2.end()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << join(vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), "|", "(", ")",
          [](char v){ return static_cast<int>(v); }) << std::endl;
}
```

outputs something like:

```
[2,4,6,8,10]
(4|8|12|16|20)
[<unprintable-char>,<unprintable-char>,<unprintable-char>,
]
(2|4|6|8|10)
```

Answer (score 1):

There was absolultey no need for super fancy stuff. Simple stuff like this would have achieved the same results.

```
int vectorCounter=0;

//this is where you loop over the contents of your vector
for (auto it = StrVec.begin(); it != StrVec.end(); ++it){
                
    vectorCounter++;
    
    //this print contents of the vector
    cout << *it;

    //this will put a custom delimiter
    if (vectorCounter < StrVec.size())
    {
        //This is where you define your delimiter
        cout << ",";
    }
}//end-for-loop


OUTPUT:
1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 1):

If the usage of [ABSL](https://abseil.io/) is ok, you could do it like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> strings{"h", "e", "ll", "o"};
auto joined(absl::StrJoin(strings, "-"));
```

See [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/oeqz8a7cM)

Boost has a [similar thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6334153/108238) like @StefanQ suggested

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35452044/14325545), but I just wanted to point out that there is an example on cppreference for  [std::accumulate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)

```cpp
std::vector<int> v {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
 
auto dash_fold = [](std::string a, int b)
{
  return std::move(a) + '-' + std::to_string(b);
};
 
std::string s = std::accumulate(std::next(v.begin()), v.end(),
                                std::to_string(v[0]),
                                dash_fold);
// s: 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10
```

Answer (score 0):

Another potential option is [`std::experimental::ostream_joiner`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ostream_joiner):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <experimental/iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> i{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    std::copy(i.begin(), i.end(), 
              std::experimental::make_ostream_joiner(std::cout, ", "));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

**NOTE:** As implied by the `experimental` namespace, this is not yet standardized and is currently not available on some compilers.  e.g. I was able to use it in GCC and Clang, but not MSVC.

Answer (score -1):

```
int array[ 6 ] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
std::vector< int > a( array, array + 6 );
stringstream dataString; 
ostream_iterator<int> output_iterator(dataString, ";"); // here ";" is delimiter 
std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), output_iterator);
cout<<dataString.str()<<endl;
```

output= 1;2;3;4;5;6;

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: This includes a trailing delimiter. Granted, the OP didn't specify but usually one places delimiters between fields and not at the end of the final field.

Answer (score -2):

faster variant:

```
vector<string> x = {"1", "2", "3"};
string res;
res.reserve(16);

std::accumulate(std::begin(x), std::end(x), 0,
                [&res](int &, string &s)
                {
                    if (!res.empty())
                    {
                        res.append(",");
                    }
                    res.append(s);
                    return 0;
               });
```

it doesn't create interim strings, but just allocate memory once for the whole string result and appends each elem to the end of &res

Comment: You're using an `accumulate()` but totally ignore that result. You should be using `std::for_each()` instead.

Comment: actually return value of this function call is 0 (see lambda -> return 0;).
but 'res' contains result string

Comment: Did you know `accumulate` expects its function to not have side-effects? This code would better be expressed as a `for_each`.