# What is the recommended way to flatten a std::vector<CString> to a multi_sz using C++ / STL

Tags: c++, string, windows, stl, atl

I want to write a list of strings (ATL::CString) stored in a std::vector to a REG_MULTI_SZ value in the Windows registry. I know how to do this in plain C (iterate once to get the total length, allocate a buffer, copy the strings to the buffer separated by "\0").

Know I tried the following using STL (sorry that I have to use VS2010 with "for each"):

```
std::vector<TCHAR> multiline_sz;
for each ( CString entry in myStringList )
{
   TCHAR* buf = entry.GetBuffer();
   multiline_sz.insert(multiline_sz.end(), &buf[0], &buf[entry.GetLength()]);
   multiline_sz.push_back(L'\0');
}
multiline_sz.push_back(L'\0');
```

This works, but I wonder if there is a more elegant or faster way using STL.

Comment: Near-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277906/stdvector-to-string-with-custom-delimiter .  The two real differences are the chosen delimiter (you want a `\0` rather than a comma), and tacking on the extra nul at the end.

Comment: Looks reasonable (given that the loop header is pseudocode). *"more elegant"*? - Probably not, since `CString` doesn't have an iterator interface. *"faster"*? - Maybe you could sum up the sizes (including the `0`s in between) beforehand and do an appropriate `multiline_sz.reserve()`, though I won't give any guarantee for a significant performance improvement (I guess/hope you won't spam the registry with entire books anyway).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CString::GetBuffer()` is already zero-terminated, so it's valid to do

```
for each ( CString entry in myStringList )
{
   TCHAR const* buf = entry.GetBuffer();
   multiline_sz.insert(multiline_sz.end(), &buf[0], &buf[entry.GetLength()+1]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. And I promise to use "for(Cstring: entry in myStringList)" as soon as I am allowed to switch to VS2012 :).

Comment: @majo Won't work either. It's `for(auto &&entry : myStringList)`, or `for(auto iter=myStringList.begin(); iter!=myStringList.end(); ++iter)` if you're not allowed to switch.

Comment: @ChristianRau: `for (const auto& entry : myStringList)` would work just fine for compilers implementing C++11 range-for loops. BTW I think this answer from 2013 is wrong since it uses `CString::GetBuffer()` instead of **`CString::GetString()`**. Moreover, the `&buf[index]` syntax is superfluous in this case and can be simplified. I've posted what I think is a better answer a few days ago.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using **`CString::GetString()`** (instead of `CString::GetBuffer()`), as it returns a pointer to the NUL-terminated string for *read-only* access.

Moreover, note also that `CString::GetBuffer()` requires a matching `CString::ReleaseBuffer()` call.

I'd also simplify your code, without the unnecessary `&buf[0]`, `&buf[<index>]` syntax.

```
// Your pseudo code: 
// for each ( CString entry in myStringList )
{
  multiline_sz.insert(
      multiline_sz.end(), 
      entry.GetString(), // <-- current string's start
      entry.GetString() + entry.GetLength() + 1 // <-- include terminating NUL
  );
}
```

As a further optimization, you may scan the whole input string list, and pre-compute the *total* required length, and call `std::vector::reserve()` to pre-allocate room in the vector, before the `vector::insert()` calls. That would save you some reallocations and copies during the insertion process.

---

**P.S.** If you want to iterate through a `std::vector<CString>` with C++11 **range-for** loops, you can use this syntax:

```
for (const auto& entry : myStringList)
```