# How can I read a file with lines of different number of numbers

Tags: c++, file-io, readfile

I am trying to read in a file of data, approx 2000 lines, the file looks something like

```
1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5
1.6     1.7 1.8 1.9 
2.0
2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5
```

There  is actually a blank (white space) and 1.3/1.7 are in the same column

The way I have it setup as storing is a vector of structs where

```
struct num
{
    double d1, d2, d3, d4, d5;
};
```

What I am trying to achieve is

```
num A;
vector<num> data
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    File >> A.d1 >> A.d2 >> A.d3 >> A.d4 >> A.d5;
    data.push_back(A);
}
```

and to find the logic to recognize the blank space in the second line and store d1=1.6, d2=0, d3=1.7 etc.. and the third line to be d1=2.0 and the d2,d3,d4,d5=0
I am just confused on how to test/get the logic for implementing this, if possible
I am in C++ VS2010
After looking at the first answer thought I should provide more info, each line in the file belongs to a satellite, and each number represents an observation on a specific wavelength, so if it is blank it means it has no observations on that wavelength.

So to elaborate, first line represents satellite 1 has an observation on all 5 wavelengths, line 2 reprsents satelittle 2 and has observations on wavelength 1,3,4,5 and none on wavelength 4.

Thats why I am trying to break it into each line as a seperate struct, because each line is a seperate satellite

Comment: I'm assuming that the line with `2.0` has blanks as well after it? That is, 8 of them?

Answer (score 2):

Observing your data:

- Every data point is stored in the following pattern: data, space.
- If a data point doesn't exist, it is represented by a space, unless it is the last non-existent data point where all other output is truncated to a newline.

This is what I came up with:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

//note all the lines are stored WITH newlines at the end of them.
//This is merely an artifact of the methodology I am using,
//as the newline is a flag that truncates output (as per your problem)
vector<string> preparse_input(const std::string& filename) {
    vector<string> lines;

    ifstream ifile;

    ifile.open(filename.c_str(), ios::in);
    if (!ifile.is_open()) {
        exit(1);
    }

    string temp, chars, line;
    char ch;

    while(getline(ifile, temp)) {
        temp += "\n";//getline removes the newline: because we need it, reinsert it
        istringstream iss(temp);

        //first read in the line char by char
        while(iss >> noskipws >> ch) {
            chars += ch;
        }

        bool replaced_newline = false;
        int nargs = 0;

        //I could have used iterators here, but IMO, this way is easier to read. Modify if need be.
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.size(); ++i) {
            if (isdigit(chars[i]) && chars[i+1] == ' ') {
                nargs += 1;
            }
            else if(isspace(chars[i]) && isspace(chars[i+1])) {
                if (chars[i+1] == '\n') {
                    replaced_newline = true;
                }
                //this means that there is no value set
                //hence, set the value to 0 for the value part:
                chars[i+1] = '0';
                line += chars[i];
                ++i;//now, skip to the next character since 1 is for spacing, the other is for the value
                nargs += 1;
            }

            //now rebuild the line:
            line += chars[i];

            if(isdigit(chars[i]) && chars[i+1] == '\n') {
                nargs += 1;
                //check nargs:
                for (int i = nargs; i < 5; ++i) {
                    line += " 0";
                    nargs += 1;
                }
            }

            if (replaced_newline) {
                line += '\n';
            }
            replaced_newline = false;
        }

        lines.push_back(line);
        chars.clear();
        line.clear();
    }
    ifile.close();

    return lines;
}

//this way, it's much easier to adapt to any type of input that you may have
template <typename T>
vector< vector<T> > parse_input (const vector<string>& lines) {
    vector< vector<T> > values;
    T val = 0;

    for(vector<string>::const_iterator it = lines.begin(); it != lines.end(); ++it) {
        vector<T> line;
        istringstream iss(*it);
        string temp;

        while(getline(iss, temp, ' ')) {
            if (istringstream(temp) >> val) {
                line.push_back(val);
            }
            else {
                line.push_back(0);//this is the value that badly parsed values will be set to.
                            //you have the option of setting it to some sentinel value, say -1, so you can go back and correct it later on, if need be. Depending on how you want to treat this error - hard or soft (stop program execution vs adapt and continue parsing), then you can adapt it accordingly
                            //I opted to treat it as a soft error but without a sentinel value - so I set it to 0 (-1 as that is probably more applicable in a general case), and informed the user that an error occurred
                            //The flipside of that is that I could have treated this as a hard error and have `exit(2)` (or whatever error code you wish to set).
                cerr << "There was a problem storing:\"" << temp << "\"\n";
            }
        }
        values.push_back(line);
    }
    return values;
}

int main() {
    string filename = "data.dat";
    vector<string> lines = preparse_input(filename);

    vector < vector<double> > values = parse_input<double>(lines);

    for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < values[i].size(); ++j) {
            cout << values[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Summarily, I broke down the string by reading each line character by character, and then rebuilding each line by replacing the blanks with `0` for easier parsing. Why? Because without some value like that, there is no way to tell which parameter was stored or skipped (using the default `ifstream_object >> type` methodology).

This way, if I then use `stringstream` objects to parse the input I can correctly determine which parameter is set, or not set; then, store the results and everything is dandy. Which is what you desire.

And, using it on the following data:

```
1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5
1.6   1.7 1.8 1.9
2.0        
2.0
2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5
2.1     2.4
```

Gives you the output:

```
1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5
1.6 0 1.7 1.8 1.9
2 0 0 0 0
2 0 0 0 0
2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5
2.1 0 0 2.4 0
```

NOTE: Line 3 has 8 spaces (1 for no data and 1 for spacing). Line 4 is the line from your original data. Line 6 contains 5 spaces (following the pattern cited).

Lastly, let me say that **this is by far, one of the most insane methods of storing data I've ever encountered.**

Comment: I am hard pressed to find more insane formats, xml comes to mind but people don't tend to agree with me on that one.

Comment: I appreciate this, it is a huge help!!
As for the storing of the data, I didnt know any other way to store it and access it efficiently being that each line represents 1 satellite and their are 2000 lines. Would you have any recommendations on how to store it to keep each line separate from each other

Comment: @user2840470: If my response has been useful to you, please consider it for acceptance. :) That aside, it would be better to use non-whitespace delimited data formats such as csv. That way if the first 3 columns of data were missing, there wouldn't be any second guessing: `,,,4.1,2.3`. Something like that. But, that's another story. Overall, it may be overkill to use only C++ to do all that parsing for you. Ideally, you could use another language in tandem with C++, say Python, to help you with the data pre-processing.

Answer (score 1):

Given your file format is space delimited you can extract the columns using a regular expression.  I've assumed you can use C++11 or if not Boost regex.

Then you can use the following function to split a string into tokens.

```
std::vector<std::string> split(const std::string& input, const std::regex& regex) {
    // passing -1 as the submatch index parameter performs splitting
    std::sregex_token_iterator
        first(input.begin(), input.end(), regex, -1),
        last;
    return std::vector<std::string>(first, last);
}
```

As an example, assuming your data is in "data.txt", I used it this way to get the values:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

std::vector<std::string> split(const string& input, const regex& regex) {
    // passing -1 as the submatch index parameter performs splitting
    std::sregex_token_iterator
        first(input.begin(), input.end(), regex, -1),
        last;
    return vector<std::string>(first, last);
}

int main()
{
    ifstream f("data.txt");

    string s;
    while (getline(f, s))
    {
        vector<string> values = split(s, regex("\\s"));
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < values.size(); ++i)
        {
            cout << "[" << values[i] << "] ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which gives the following results:

```
[1.1] [1.2] [1.3] [1.4] [1.5]
[1.6] [] [1.7] [1.8] [1.9]
[2.0] [] [] []
[2.1] [2.2] [2.3] [2.4] [2.5]
```

Note, there is a missing column in row 4, but that's because I'm not quite sure how many white spaces you have on that line.  If you know there is no more than 5 columns than it could be corrected in the output stage.

Hopefully you find this approach helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `std:vector` to hold an array of floats.

To add a new element to the vector you use:

[std::vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)

As you read in each character, look to see if it is a digit or a period.

If it is, add that to a `std::string`, and then use `atof` with `mystring.c_str()` as the parameter to convert it to a float.

This may also help convert a string to float:

[std::string to float or double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012571/stdstring-to-float-or-double)

So, read into a string, then push the float to a vector, and repeat, skipping characters that are not a digit or a period.

At the end of the line your vector has all the floats, and if you want to join them into a string with a custom delimiter you can look at the answers to this question:

[std::vector to string with custom delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277906/stdvector-to-string-with-custom-delimiter)

Comment: Because the way I need to access the information I need it seperated. Each line represents 5 observations from a single satellite on different wavelengths, if it is blank it means it doesnt have an observation on that wavelength.

Comment: So if there is a missing observation, then just have an empty element, and just use and float observation[5] instead and make certain to call memset before each loop (to quickly clean out the array).