# Is there an out of the box function for performing the reverse a string splitter?

Tags: c++, boost

In order to split a string into a vector I use

```
std::vector<std::string> v;
boost::split(v, input, boost::is_any_of("|"));
```

is there a function either in Boost or STL that performs the reverse of this operation, i.e. a join function, of the form

```
join(v, output, "|")
```

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the section named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: [boost::join](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/join.html) ?

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277906/stdvector-to-string-with-custom-delimiter

Comment: @Jarod42: Thanks - careless of me to not see that -, do please put as an answer and I'll vote and accept.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Could you please reference the parts of those pages that explicitly makes my question off topic?

Comment: @P45Imminent "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Asking for functions (even in the standard library) is off-topic. If you had *tried* something, and included an [mcve] and explained how your attempt didn't work (with expected and actual output) then that would be pretty good question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is [`boost::join`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/join.html):

```
std::vector<std::string> v = {"Hello", "world"};
const std::string separator = " ";
std::string s = boost::join(v, separator);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd29f908a57d35a9)

Answer (score -2):

Yes there is such a function, it is called [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v { "a", "b" };
    std::string r = std::accumulate( v.begin(), v.end(), std::string(""),[](std::string a,std::string b){ return a + " | " + b; });
    std::cout << r;
}
```

output:

```
 | a | b
```

Handling the boundaries correct (no `|` in the beginning), the code gets a tiny bit more verbose: pass `v.begin() + 1` and the inital string accordingly, but take care of the edge case of an empty `v`.

However, not that this naive application of `std::accumulate` is far from being efficient (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18703743/4117728) for details).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18703743/10933809.downvote is not mine

Comment: @Oblivion i stoped caring about votes some time ago... I dont get the `O(n^2)` argument in the link you posted. Passing around reference instead of values is something I considered already when writing the answer and actually dont remember why I didnt do it. PS: I do care about constructive critisism, so thanks for the link