# Combine all elements in vector into a new string MFC VC++

Tags: vector, visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to combine all the elements inside a vector as a new string but I can't get the example how to do this. Most of the examples are concatenating between vectors and also in C++ `std::cout`. I'm not sure how to do it in MFC VC++.

Let's say I have a vector (in CString) with the elements `I am` `a naughty` `boy`. How can I combine them and saved them as a

`CString str;`

`str = "I am a naughty boy"`

Edited:

```
struct REVLISTDATA {
CString str_;
REVLISTDATA(CString str_element) : str_(str_element) {}
};
std::vector<REVLISTDATA> vec;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::vector to string with custom delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277906/stdvector-to-string-with-custom-delimiter)

Comment: So far not, I'm not sure how to apply them in VC++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am well understood your request, here is an approach:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
{
    str.AppendFormat(vec.at(i));
    if (i < vec.size() - 1)
        str.AppendFormat(_T(" "));  // spaces between words
}
```

presuming that your **vec** is `std::vector<CString>`

**Edit:** So, instead of `str.AppendFormat(vec.at(i));` you should use `str.AppendFormat(vec.at(i).str_);`

**Later edit:** I have tried the following code and work ok:

```
struct REVLISTDATA
{
    CString str_;
    REVLISTDATA(CString str_element) : str_(str_element) {}
};

std::vector<REVLISTDATA> vec;

vec.push_back(REVLISTDATA("I"));
vec.push_back(REVLISTDATA("am"));
vec.push_back(REVLISTDATA("a"));
vec.push_back(REVLISTDATA("naughty"));
vec.push_back(REVLISTDATA("boy"));

CString str;
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
{
    str.AppendFormat(vec.at(i).str_);
    if (i < vec.size() - 1)
        str.AppendFormat(_T(" "));  // spaces between words
}
```

So, I guess you exception is coming from other way.

Comment: yes, I have updated the vector in the question, it is in CString, correct?? But there is an error on this line `str.AppendFormat(vec.at(i));` and the output shows _error C2664: 'void ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>::AppendFormat(const wchar_t *,...)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'REVLISTDATA' to 'UINT'_

Comment: I tried to put other string inside the vector and it get this error _0xC0000005: Access violation reading location_.

Comment: I guess you are trying to access an object that don't exist. I'll prepare a little bit later a piece of code for you.

Comment: Found the root cause, it is the mistake when I push_back the string into the vector. The code works fine!