# Write all elements of string array to a single string

Tags: c++, arrays, string, function

I currently have a function that I want to return a single string, but I want it to return all elements of a string array in a single string which the function can return. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Use `std::stringstream` from `#include <sstream>` to concatenate your strings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689003/how-to-implode-a-vector-of-strings-into-a-string-the-elegant-way

Comment: Please show what, if any, code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do like this:

```
string f()
{
  string s1 ="Hello ";
  string s2 = "world!";

  stringstream ss;

  ss<< s1;
  ss<< s2;

  return ss.str();
 }
```