# How to store a const char* [] in std :: string?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
const char * tag1[]={"abc","xyz"};
```

how to convert tag1 in std::string?

```
std::string tag2(tag1)
```

it simply copies tag1[0] to tag2. what i want is to convert the whole tag1 array into string.

Any ideas or workaround?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?? `string` is a string, not a list of strings.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : i simply want to convert the whole tag1 array into a single string.

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689003/how-to-implode-a-vector-of-strings-into-a-string-the-elegant-way
NB: Arrays are evil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to merge array of C-strings into one std::string, you can do this:

```
std::string tag2;   
for (auto ptr : tag1) {
    tag2.append(ptr);   
}
```

Iterate over C-strings array and append them to destination std::string.

Direct copy of tag1 array to pre-allocated std::string won't work because of null-terminators at end of each C-string in tag1. You will get `abc\0xyz`, instead of `abcxyz`

Comment: probably calculating the total size and reserving is a bit more efficient without carpifying the code much