# Join (concatenate) vector of strings to char buffer with zero byte as delimiter/terminator

Tags: c++, string

Is there any better way to convert vector of string to the vector of chars with zero terminator between strings.

So if I have a vector with the following strings `"test","my","string"`, then I want to receive one vector of chars: `"test\0my\0string\0"`.

At this moment this code works fine, but is there any better (more beautiful) solution?

```
std::vector<std::string> string_array = {"test", "my", "string"};
std::vector<char> buffer_temp;
for (auto &str : string_array)
{
    for (auto &chr : str)
    {
        buffer_temp.push_back(chr);
    }
    buffer_temp.push_back('\0');
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with that code? Define "beautiful".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implode a vector of strings into a string (the elegant way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689003/how-to-implode-a-vector-of-strings-into-a-string-the-elegant-way)

Comment: @Lundin get your facts straight, `std::string` is not null-terminated.

Comment: @n.m. When you push back the string into the char array, a null terminator gets appended. Simply print the raw data of the char vector and see for yourself. I guess this sequence on my screen is just me smoking C++1x weed, right? `116
101
115
116
0
109
121
0
115
116
114
105
110
103
0
0`

Comment: @Lundin Pushing raw data is not the same as iterating the string. Run the damn code and see what it does.

Comment: @n.m. Which I did before posting the comment. Why don't you run it yourself.

Comment: @Lundin when you iterate a `std::string`, you won't observe a null terminator.

Comment: @Lundin http://ideone.com/dFqwy9

Comment: @moooeeeep Iterate the character vector, obviously.

Comment: @Lundin:  Don't be sarky.  There are a number of Windows API calls where this is *exactly* the memory layout that is required.

Comment: @moooeeeep And? What has iterating a std::string got to do with anything? I'm talking about the code in the question.

Comment: In addition, the standard does not require that the std::string contains a null terminator (it can be appended by .c_str()).  The fact that all existing implementations do append one is neither here nor there.

Comment: @MartinBonner With 2 null terminators at the end?

Comment: Yes.  That's how the code knows it has got to the end of the series of strings.

Comment: @MartinBonner More commonly they would use a NULL pointer as sentinel. But if you say so.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not sure what exactly you ran but [here goes](http://ideone.com/UC6Zjo)

Comment: @Lundin: How do you store a NULL pointer in a char buffer?  The code to iterate over the sequence of strings is `for (; *p; p += strlen(p)+1) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never forget the [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) method with which your example can be simplified as follows:

```
std::vector<std::string> string_array = { "test", "my", "string" };
std::vector<char> buffer_temp;

for(auto& s : string_array)
    buffer_temp.insert(buffer_temp.end(), s.c_str(), s.c_str() + s.size() + 1);
```

The `std::string::c_str` returns a pointer to a null-terminated character array, so you don't have to append an extra `'\0'` to the end of each element coming from your `string_array`.

---

Responding to comments below, you can use `std::string` iterators as well, and because the `std::string` has random-access iterator you can do the following:

```
for(auto& s : string_array)
    buffer_temp.insert(buffer_temp.end(), s.begin(), s.end() + 1);
```

Comment: If you use stringstream, you can access the char array directly via ss.str().data(). There is no need to copy it to buffer_temp.

Comment: I've removed the `std::stringstream` example since there is no need to it if the desired delimiter is `'\0'`.

Comment: You should change that to `{ buffer_temp.insert(buffer_temp.end(), s.begin(), s.end()); buffer_temp.push_back('\0'); }` - just because it looks more innocent.

Answer (score 1):

Directly copying the string data might be faster for long strings.

```
 std::vector<std::string> string_array = {"test", "my", "string"};
 int size = 0;
 for (auto &str : string_array)
 {
     size += str.size()+1;
 }

 char * buffer = new char[size];
 int cursor = 0;
 for (auto &str : string_array)
 {
     memcpy(&buffer[cursor], str.data(), str.size());
     cursor += str.size()+1;
     buffer[cursor-1] = '\0';
 }
```

Comment: I would write `std::vector<char> buffer(size);` and `size_t cursor;`.  You can also write `memcpy(&buffer[cursor], str.c_str(), str.size()+1);` to copy the zero terminator as well.  (In *theory*, `.c_str()` can allocate a new buffer, but no actual implementation does this.)

Comment: You should not copy into the raw char data of a string object (there is a reason why it is const char*), this is why I prefer a char array.