# Did Boost::algorithms get subsumed into standard libraries?

Tags: c++, boost, stl, tr1

Starting in C++11 (I think) a lot of Boost functionality was available in the STL, or in an extension TR1 (again, if memory serves).

I'm struggling to tell specifically which things were and were not included in C++11 and later versions (and in MSVC++ versions).

Specifically this very old question about joining `vector<string>` has a nice Boost-based answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6334153/197229.

I don't want to add boost dependency to my project so - is this functionality now available in standard libraries?

Comment: It seems an area where a lot of popular, answered questions are out of date - more for Meta but how should we handle the case questions get better answers years later due to language/library changes?

Answer (score 4):

`boost::algorithm::join` is not part of the C++ standard library. (nor something with equivalent functionality).

More generally, sometimes things are implemented in Boost.Algorithm and then proposed for standardization (Boyer-Moore, for example), and sometimes I implement things that have been added to the standard library in Boost.Algorithm for people who can't/won't use the latest C++ version (`any_of`, for example).

Answer (score 2):

`boost::algorithm::join` has not made its way into the standard library as of yet.  There is an open paper ([N3594](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3594.html)) to have it added to the library, but it is sitting in the Library Evolution working group currently.

You'll either need to use one of the other implementations from that Q&A pair or include boost.